# Почему не стартует FTP на Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vsftpd

Поставил vsftpd команда `systemctl status vsftpd` показывает:

```
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-04-18 23:29:25 MSK; 35s ago
Process: 19299 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd.conf (code=exited, status=2)
```

Что-то не так в конфиге вероятно. Ок, я включил в конфиге логи (раскомментировал строку):

```
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
```

При запуске, перезапуске в var/log файл vsftpd.log не появился. Что можно предпринять, есть ли какой-то инструмент тестирования конфигурации? Что-то типа  `nginx -t` или  `nginx -c`

Файла `var/log/messages` не существует.

journalctl -xe говорит что пароли кто-то перебирает вроде...

```
23:47:10 srv.dm.ru sshd[19453]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
23:47:10 srv.dm.ru sshd[19453]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=
23:47:12 srv.dm.ru sshd[19453]: Failed password for invalid user default from 5.188.10.176 port 42990 ssh2
23:47:12 srv.dm.ru sshd[19453]: Connection closed by 5.188.10.176 port 42990 [preauth]
```

в syslog последние записи 15 минут назад, о vsftpd ничего из последнего нет:

```
22:49:29 srv apache2[18475]:  * Stopping Apache httpd web server apache2
22:49:30 srv apache2[18475]:  *
22:49:30 srv apache2[18499]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
22:49:31 srv apache2[18499]:  *
23:09:01 srv CRON[19101]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && /usr/lib/php/sessionclean)
23:34:01 srv CRON[19313]: (root) CMD (cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
23:39:01 srv CRON[19347]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && /usr/lib/php/sessionclean)
```

Comment: xferlog - это файл для записи трансфера данных. В него не пишутся данные о состоянии/ошибках и т.д. Это касается не только vsftpd, но и других известных FTP (proftpd, wu-ftpd). Что реально прошло не так, надо смотреть в syslog-e - /var/log/syslog или /var/log/messages. Либо воспользоваться командой `journalctl -xe`.

Comment: @defrag обновил ответ, лога messages не существует, в syslog об этой проблеме ничего, в `journalctl -xe` тоже (добавил логи в вопрос)

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался

```
listen=YES
```

но

```
listen_ipv6=NO
```